# SQL 2005 sql login ip restriction

Tags: sql-server, security, authentication

Is there a way to restrict a specific SQL 2005 login on a Microsoft SQL Server 2005, standard version (sql is in mixed mode) to specific IP addresses, while other logins, Windows authenticated ones, are unaffected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do this.  You'll need to write a logon trigger as described here:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb326598.aspx

I futzed around with it for the last fifteen minutes and had limited success, but maybe there's somebody else on here who's done a DDL logon trigger filtering by IP address that can show the source code.

Answer (score 5):

I use the following trigger to restrict access to specific login - IPs combo.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [LOGIN_IP_RESTRICTION]
    ON ALL SERVER FOR LOGON
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @host NVARCHAR(255);

    SET @host = EVENTDATA().value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ClientHost)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)');

    IF(EXISTS(SELECT * FROM master.dbo.IP_RESTRICTION 
        WHERE UserName = SYSTEM_USER))
    BEGIN
        IF(NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM master.dbo.IP_RESTRICTION 
            WHERE UserName = SYSTEM_USER AND ValidIP = @host))
        BEGIN
            ROLLBACK;
        END
    END
END;
```

DDL for table IP_RESTRICTION:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[IP_RESTRICTION](
    [UserName] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [ValidIP] [varchar](15) NOT NULL,
    [Comment] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_IP_RESTRICTION] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
([UserName] ASC, [ValidIP] ASC) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Answer (score 2):

**A few words of warning!**

If you get **anything** wrong with this script, and logoff before you realise it, you will have just locked yourself out of the SQL Server.

You will then need to restart the server offline in minimal mode -f

Then DROP TRIGGER [LOGIN_IP_RESTRICTION] ON ALL SERVER

Then you have a chance of getting back in. How do I know? I just made that mistake, and had a few bowel-loosening moments before I figured out how to get back in and remove the trigger.

Answer (score 1):

I have restricted logins on my system to a single IP address, just use the firewall.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server can be mapped to several port/IP configurations by the Server Manager, but AFAIK there isn't a way to bind a login method to a port/IP.

The only thing I can think of is to create a trigger FOR LOGON and inside that trigger test the Event Data like:

SELECT EVENTDATA().value ('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/LoginType)','nvarchar(max)'), 
       EVENTDATA().value ('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ClientHost)','nvarchar(max)')

...and maybe calling RAISEERROR or ROLLBACK if you don't like what you find might terminate the connection?

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to restrict by IP address?  If all your users are authenticated, just set up group permissions on SQL Server, and allow or deny the groups you want.

If the problem is various users using applications with the same SQL login (you mentioned you're using mixed-mode), then the question is why do you want to allow some users using the applications to access SQL Server, and not allow others?  Implement the security in the applications, don't bounce them at the database level.

Comment: I don't "want" to, but it's a mixture off applications, and I have no control over those. These apps are accessing the DB with an sql login, without possibility to configure. So I want to ensure that the apps are still accessing the db, while any other sources, like developer desktops, are denied.

Comment: Are the apps PC or server based?  If they are PC based, then the apps will come from the users' computers, and so you can't filter by IP.  If they are server based (e.g. on a corporate intranet), then hopefully the users don't have the database username/password, so they have no access to the db.